# How do I replace every odd occurrence of a substring with regex in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to change the following

```
<evenInstance><evenInstance><evenInstance><evenInstance><evenInstance>
```

to

```
<oddInstance><evenInstance><oddInstance><evenInstance><oddInstance>
```

I have gotten the following

```
<oddInstance><oddInstance><oddInstance><oddInstance><oddInstance><oddInstance>
```

to be

```
<oddInstance><evenInstance><oddInstance><evenInstance><oddInstance><evenInstance>
```

with the regex:

```
(odd(?:(?!odd).)*)odd((?:(?!odd).)*)
```

and the substitution:

```
\1even\2
```

But I don't know how to do it for odd occurrences. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest way to do it.
Uses the `\G` construct.

`(?s)(?:even|(?!^)\G.*?even.*?\Keven)`

https://regex101.com/r/8BlRJx/1

Formatted

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      even
   |  
      (?! ^ )
      \G 
      .*? even .*? \K even
 )
```

Benchmark

```
Regex1:   (?:even|(?!^)\G.*?even.*?\Keven)
Completed iterations:   3  /  3     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   186
Elapsed Time:    1.02 s,   1023.95 ms,   1023953 µs
Matches per sec:   544,946
```

Answer (score 1):

The first pattern might be shortened to

```
odd\Kodd(?=(?:oddodd)*$)
```

Replace with `even`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOBg0B/1)

Result

> oddevenoddevenoddeven

For the second pattern you might use:

```
even(?=(?:eveneven)*$)
```

Replace with `odd`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzsxMs/1)

Result

> oddevenoddevenodd